# Laravel - retrieving attribute from within a model relationship in a blade view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, view

I have created a relationship between products and users using a foreign key called "`previous_owner`". I can see when I dump the value that I'm passing to the view that the data I'm after is available under:

```
$product->relations->product_owner->user->attributes->name
```

But how do I access it from within my view. I'm trying to loop through the products and then do something like:

```
{{ $product->product_owner->user->name }}
```

or

```
{{ $product->product_owner->name }}
```

But non of it works, keep getting:

**" Trying to get property 'name' of non-object "**

[image: SCREEN GRAB OF THE OBJECT]

Comment: Please run a `dd($product->product_owner);` and tell me the result.

Comment: Your relationship function name `product_owner` and foreign key `product_owner` is same! It's confusing, therefore either you have to change the relation function name to something other than FK or force it by calling the function as `product_owner()` + Try my answer!

Comment: The function and the FK are not the same, the FK is called previous_owner_id and the function is called product_owner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view code must be similar this

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    {{ $product->product_owner->name }}
@endforeach
```

This code mean each product has product_owner. When one product does not have `product_owner` that case value of `$product->product_owner` is Null and then your code is `null->name` and you get error. For fix it you must be check relation is null or use `??` operator. Change your code to

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    {{ $product->product_owner->name ?? ''}}
@endforeach
```

or

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    @if($product->product_owner)
        {{ $product->product_owner->name}}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: This was indeed the problem, I had some holes in my test data. I re ran the seeders and then it worked just fine. That said, didn't know about this conversion so good learning for me, will use it moving forward to ensure I don't get this error again for the same reason. Thanks heaps!!!

Answer (score 2):

If `name` is attribute and `product_owner` is relationship function then try the below:

```
{{ $product->product_owner()->name }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your product_owner isn't stdClass. It is array. So you can't access this key of this array with "->"  operator. try

```
{{ $product->product_owner['name'] }}
```